# C# data repositories: Bundling & flushing data in intervals. Pattern to make fail-safe against app shutdown/crashes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to come up with a repository that can by itself bundle several items to be added to the database, and then perform a bulk insert operation in certain intervals. Something like

```
public interface MyRepository
{
  void InsertDeferred(DTO.Item item);
}
```

The repository would bundle all items, and every 30 seconds or so perform a bulk insert-operation to the underlying SQLite database (via EFCore) with all items that were added since the last flush.

Is there any pattern to do this as fail-safe as possible? Otherwise, what if the application shuts down (expectedly or unexpecdetly) just before the next flush, lots of data that might be lost...

I think the major logging libraries (log4net etc.), for example, also optionally only flush their writes in interval - does anyone know if they maybe came up with a clever way to prevent or minimize data loss?

Thanks!

Comment: Serialize pending items to disk?

Comment: Hmm, I think that might defy a part of the purpose of what I'm aiming for - i.e. avoid trying to write to a SQLite-file a few hundred/thousand times a second, by instead trying to write to other files as much

Comment: Well if you want to avoid losing data - you need to store it in some persistent storage (not RAM) - there is no orher way.

Comment: Bummer, thanks - was hoping something similar like deterministic constructors was "fakeable" somehow, which may have covered most cases except for a shutdown of the entire machine or such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would write to a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx), and have a single thread reading from there and writing to disk.  You can control the potential data loss with the size of the BlockingCollection, and whether you have the reading thread wait for a certain interval or minimum number of items before flushing to disk.